# I need a specific method to call itself 3 times a day, at 7am, 2pm, and 9pm, is a web service what I need? And how would I call it?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, web-services

I read it was recommended to use regular Windows Services instead, or a Console App you could start with the task scheduler, the issue here is that I won't be able to have access to the server much less to configure it myself after my website is up, so we had come up with the idea of setting up a web service that could do the work automatically at those specific times, I've created a web service already, but I can't see how to make it automatic, so far it's only my website caling the web services methods, which is completely useless since I could do that from the website itself.

This is the example form VS, I can call it from my own code but it serves no purpose.

```
<WebMethod()> _
 Public Function HelloWorld() As String
  Return "Hello World"
 End Function
```

So assumming this is what I need, how could I make it automatic?

Answer (score 0):

If what you need is some solution that will run some routine at configured time and provide access to itself via http, you can:

1. make a web service,
2. use Quartz.NET http://quartznet.sourceforge.net/ to schedule routine,
3. use WCF self hosting for providing HTTP access